# C#,ASP.NET: Formatting a GRIDVIEW row Based on Content

Tags: asp.net

Greetings Gurus. I have a gridview who's rows I need to higlight if the 'Status' field is null. The code below throws an exception. I'm getting a "Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.DataItem' cannot be used like a method". I think I'm really close but I don't know where to turn next.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && 
     e.Row.DataItem("Status") == null)
    {
           // e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

basic

```
CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("Status") = null
```

c#

```
((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Status"] == null
```

or do it in more than one line -- see example here:
[msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at this in a long while but do you access DataItem like an array??

e.Row.DataItem("Status") would be e.Row.DataItem["Status"]

[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx)

// Retrieve the underlying data item. In this example
  // the underlying data item is a DataRowView object. 
  DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

// Retrieve the state value for the current row. 
  String state = rowView["state"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Try casting:

```
if (((MyType)e.Row.DataItem).Status == null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [sample code at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx).

The key points are:

- Cast your DataRow to a DataRowView,
  like this:

  `DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;`
- You can then retrieve values like
  this:

  `// Retrieve the status value for the current row.` 
  `Status status = (Status)rowView["status"];`

...or cast to whatever type Status happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It may not be the best solution but it works.

```
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
        DataRowView test = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        string Active = test.Row[4].ToString();

       if(Active == "")
       {
           e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Sienna;
           e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
       }
    }
```